# How to get multiple lines on Line Chart when selecting multiple values on a slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Line chart represents counts for each year based on year slicer. Which is works fine.

However, when selecting multiple years on a slicer, line chart does not display anything.

Is any way to make it display multiple lines based on multiple selection on a slicer?

Measure :

```
Total Submitted Test = 
    IF(SELECTEDVALUE(dim_Date[Year]) = 2017, CALCULATE([Total Submitted],dim_Date[Year] = 2017),
    IF(SELECTEDVALUE(dim_Date[Year]) = 2018, CALCULATE([Total Submitted],dim_Date[Year] = 2018),
    IF(SELECTEDVALUE(dim_Date[Year]) = 2019, CALCULATE([Total Submitted],dim_Date[Year] = 2019),
    IF(SELECTEDVALUE(dim_Date[Year]) = 2020, CALCULATE([Total Submitted],dim_Date[Year] = 2020)
    ))))
```

[image]

---

**Expected result:**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Not using any legends. But still, when selecting multiple years only 1 line displays.

[image]

Comment: Can you not just use the `[Total Submitted]` measure with Year in the Legend box?

Comment: Not sure why you are thinking this so complex! Just add Month to Axis, Year to Legend, [Total Submitted] to Values field and you should get your required output.

Comment: @Alexis. Not sure what you mean by that, I am not using anything in Legend box. Snip attached.

Comment: I'm recommending that you **do** use the Legend box. Try putting the Year column in that box.

Comment: oh! I went too complicated way! Thank you! Please, post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage it by  `show/hide measures in Line Chart`

https://ilovepowerbi.tips/2019/12/23/dynamically-show-hide-measures-in-line-chart-visuals-with-multiselect-slicer-in-power-bi/